# Loop through 41000 xml files

Tags: php, xml, laravel-5, simplexml

I have 41,000 xml files to loop through I am using Laravel framework.

I am after the best way in which I won't run out of memory or take too long to complete but each file I need to look at the file look inside the file and then move the file to a specific folder.

Any thoughts on what I can do?

Comment: Run it as a background task, or an artisan command, so that the time doesn't matter; use the XMLReader pull parser so that it doesn't load the entirety of every file into memory

Comment: That's what i was thinking! Just wanted to get some advice

Comment: I don't know anything about the Laravel framework, but I would consider using xmlsh for this task.